# Regex java a regular expression for extraction the first alphabetical caracters

Tags: java, regex, string

How to extract first alphabetical characters in Java, for example after applying regex on the string "ABD123EZ13 I should get "ABD", Is this possible, I searched for a while and didn't find any thing.

I find this regex :

```
String firstThreeCharacters = str.replaceAll("(?i)^[^a-z]*([a-z])[^a-z]*([a-z])[^a-z]*([a-z]).*$", "$1$2$3")
```

To extract the first n caracters, but it doesn't check if a th caracters are alphabetical or not.

Other Examples:

"AAAA" => "AAAA"

"1231" => ""

"_abvbv" => ""

"abd_12df" => "abd"

Comment: Maybe `s.replaceFirst("\\P{L}.*", "")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
String result = s.replaceFirst("(?s)\\P{L}.*", "");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lL3C8c/1)

**Details**

- `(?s)` - a `Pattern.DOTALL` modifier to make `.` match line break cahrs
- `\\P{L}` - any char other than a Unicode letter
- `.*` - any 0+ chars, up to the end of the string.

You do not need `replaceAll` since there will be only 1 replacement operation, `replaceFirst` is fine.

If you only need to only handle ASCII letters, replace `\\P{L}`, replace with `\\P{Alpha}` that only matches any chars other than ASCII letters.

Probably a matching approach will be easiest with `^\p{L}+` or `^\p{Alpha}+` patterns that match 1 or more letters from the start of the string only:

```
String s = "abd_12df";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\p{L}+"); // or just Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]+") to get the first one or more ASCII letters
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
if (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0)); 
}
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/18Rt3O).

Comment: @AxelH `\p{L}` matches any Unicode letter. `\P{L}` is the opposite construct, it matches any char that is not a Unicode letter.

Comment: @AbdenaceurLichiheb You may get all letters at the start of the string with `^[a-zA-Z]+`

Comment: Thanks for that, actually I would like to know how those are called to be able to find more info on the possibilities. You mention `Alpha` that is only for ASCII, this is not really verbose so I guess this is documented somewhere. EDIT : find a bit of info [Unicode Categories](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category)

Comment: @AxelH It is somewhat documented at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: My bad, didn't remember those ... I guess I should have start there ;)